# Wordpress стили скрипты вниз пернести

Tags: wordpress

здрати

возможно подскажите, сам не особо понимаю в программирование, вобщем поставил сайт на

wordpress

на сайте скорости сайта

https://pagespeed.web.dev/

некоторые скрипты и стили тормозят сайт, пробовал читать статьи на эту тему в интернете, пишут что скрипты и стили лучше размещать внизу страницы, ворде как есть возможнсть это сделать через файл

functions.php

в самом шаблоне сайта, действительно там код скриптов и стилей, вот так

```
function alpha_store_theme_stylesheets() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css', array(), '3.3.4', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'alpha-store-stylesheet', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), '1.4.3', 'all' );
    // load Font Awesome css
    wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.min.css', array(), '4.7.0' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'flexslider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/flexslider.css', array(), '2.6.3' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'alpha_store_theme_stylesheets' );


function alpha_store_theme_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.js', array( 'jquery' ), '3.3.4' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'alpha-store-theme-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/customscript.js', array( 'jquery', 'flexslider' ), '1.4.3' );
    wp_localize_script( 'alpha-store-theme-js', 'objectL10n', array(
        'compare'    => esc_html__( 'Compare Product', 'alpha-store' ),
        'qview'      => esc_html__( 'Quick View', 'alpha-store' ),
    ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'flexslider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '2.6.3' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'alpha_store_theme_js' );
```

как можно все это перенести вниз страницы

и еще хотелось бы спросить, чтобы не создавать новую тему, через исходный код страницы видно шрифты от

google

но в самой теме этих строк с шрифтом нету, откуда они могут подгружаться на сайт?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно передать параметр true, ниже пример (передается после версии скрипта)

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'flexslider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '2.6.3', true );
```

Нужно смотреть, может они просто импортированы в файл стилей

Comment: скорее всего вы правильно говорите, что шрифт ссылка импортирована в файлах стилей, а что показать вам чтобы вы смогли посмотреть?

вроде как ссылки на форумах нельзя ставить

Comment: Вы  спрашивали про перенос скриптов в футер, я на него ответил - если помогло отметьте как правильный пожалуйста.
По поводу шрифтов, а зачем их искать? Менять собираетесь?

Comment: да нужно шрифты поменять, на сайте

https://pagespeed.web.dev/

пишет что шрифты тормозят сайт, видимо лучше шрифт заменить, ну и еще плагины и гугл реклама некоторые тормозят сайт, с гугл рекламой понятно ничего не сделаешь, то хотя бы скрипты и стили вниз перенести

думал может есть человек на фрилансере кто сделает, вобщем  таких там умельцев нету, то есть были но взяли деньги не смогли сделать, видимо самому у придется делать, сам то не понимаю ничего в этом, так методом проб чисто, может получится

Comment: Так мой ответ помог или нет? Или вы не пробовали? И какие у вас показатели?

Comment: получилось. все равно тормозит из за гугл рекламы, стати переноса в низ стилей не особо изменилась скорость, основное это гугл реклама тормозит, но с рекламным кодом уже тут ничего не сделаешь, или ставить или убрать

Comment: Если помог мой ответ, то отметьте пожалуйста как решение. Галочка слева от моего ответа
Да верно, стили особой роли не играют. Бывает картинки много весят если не оптимизировать. Можно только какие-нибудь костыли делать, например чтобы реклама загрузилась после какого-то определенного времени

Comment: наверно кнопки чтобы поблагодарить вас нету, только флажок и то там опции не благодарности

если можно спросить еще, например плагины куда стили плагинов прописываются, это к тому есть плагины которые грузят сайт, возможно как то поиграться с стилями возможно переместить внизу страницы или все в один файл загрузить, но непонятно куда прописываются плагина стили?

Comment: Слева от моего ответа, есть две стрелочки, одна вверх - ответ полезен. Вторая вниз - ответ не полезен. 
Можно кликнуть по стрелочке вверх - значит полезен

Comment: По поводу стилей нужно смотреть куда плагин их загружает, и на сколько это влияет на загрузку страницы

Comment: куда можно тебе написать, чтобы обговорить некоторые вещи?



не знаю может через мой компьютер этих стрелок нету, даже самому интересно стало

вот посмотри скриншот

https://ibb.co/znhy4PJ

Comment: Вот скрин
https://pastenow.ru/8a775dbfebf781d3a3559986f6a7669a

Comment: "куда можно тебе написать" -- пиши сюда. А далее разберемся что нужно